# What is the proper way to use add_rewrite_rule to remove the (question mark)?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a page called "People" with a custom template that takes in a variable called name:

example.com/people/?name=FirstLast

What I want is this:

example.com/people/FristLast

I know I need to use the add_rewrite_rule and add_rewrite_tag calls but I'm not sure how to achieve my desired result. I've tried this but I get a php error:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?name=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_tag('%name%','([^&]+)');
```

The error I get is: "Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rule() on a non-object"

I think I'm on the right path. I'm very knowledgeable with WP but this is my first attempt to the rewrite rule.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

try

```
add_action( 'init', 'addMyRules' );
function addMyRules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?name=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%name%','([^&]+)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `add_rewrite_rule` in the action hook as follows:

```
add_action('init', 'wpa8715_intit');

function wpa8715_intit() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^people/([^/]*)/?','index.php?name=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%name%','([^&]+)');
}
```