# Rewrite Custom Query string at the end of a taxonomy url

Tags: wordpress

I cant seem to figure out how to rewrite/prettify a custom query var appended to the end of a url. Ive followed a lot of blogs etc online and tried to find the answer in the wp codex but nothing is working.

```
 http://website.com/product-taxonomy/cool-products/?filtertax=24
```

I would like it resemble something like this

```
http://rockbreakers.reptileha.us/machine-type/hydraulic-hammers/24/
```

Im not looking for a server side solution though, I would rather it to be handled totally inside of WP

Comment: "filtertax" this one fixed argument right?

Comment: filtertax stays always but the value 24 will be dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to use add\_rewrite\_rule to remove the (question mark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952053/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-add-rewrite-rule-to-remove-the-question-mark)